# ReactJS data-reactid has words in Instagram source code

Tags: reactjs

If you go to Instaram and open up the console you will see that there are words used in data-reactid attribute

https://instagram.com/kyliejenner/

```
data-reactid=".0.1.0.1:$mostRecent:0.0.$0.$1036585483152156993.0.2"
```

Have a look for yourself. How did they do that ? and why is that happening ?

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `key` attribute.

When dynamically creating child components, the children can be uniquely identified via the set `key` attribute. This value will be visible in the `data-reactid` attribute in said elements after being rendered into the DOM:

```
data-reactid=".0.1.$something"
```

`something` is actually the value of the `key` attribute.

Lets say you have a `Queue` and a `QueueItem` component. The `Queue` component will have a `queueData` Array and in it's `render()` method, you'll dynamically create `QueueItem` components with a `key` attribute:

```jsx
// QueueItem component.
render: function () {
  return (
    <li>
      { this.props.name }
    </li>
  );
}

// Queue component.
render: function () {
  return (
    <ul className="queue-data">
      {
        this.state.queueData.map(queueItem => <QueueItem key={ 'most-recent-' + queueItem.id } />)
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

This will result in the following markup:

```
<ul class="queue-data" data-reactid=".0.1">
  <li data-reactid=".0.1.$most-recent-1">one</li>
  <li data-reactid=".0.1.$most-recent-2">two</li>
  <li data-reactid=".0.1.$most-recent-3">three</li>
</ul>
```

More information about dynamic children can be found [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)